# DCPs - missing component

Tags: tridion

Don't ask me how but I'm in a situation where I have DCPs published that have component ids that no longer exists in Tridion!

I know the GUI will stop you deleting a component if its published but somehow (perhaps unpublishing failed but the CM still deleted the component???), they've been removed from the CM and now I've a load of DCPs in broker I can't get rid off!

Anyone ever experienced this? 
Anyway to rectify other than manually updating db?

This is Tridion 2011 setup, single deployer, single broker db.

Comment: Hmm.. You could try checking the incoming folders(failed folder) of http upload and get the package (zip) associated with Unpublishand put it back on incoming folder, so the http upload picks up this and start undeploying. Word of caution: This is not the supported way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most common **supported** way to solve this is to manually create a transport package that removes the offending DCPs.

So:

1. Set Cleanup to False in your cd_deployer_conf.xml
2. Unpublish any DCP
3. Capture the transport zip file
4. Open the instructions.xml in the zip
5. Change it to point to your DCP
6. Drop the updated zip file into your deployer's incoming folder

Comment: Thanks Frank - Ill give it a go. Any idea how this could have occurred?

Comment: Nope. If you find a way to consistently reproduce this, SDL development would love to hear. I must admit that I'll suspect "rogue API calls" until that time. ;-)

Comment: Frank, Im using HTTP(s) deployer will that make a difference? Drop my modified zip in the incoming folder but nothing happened?

Comment: This used to be reproducible by calling Component.Render from a template. This would publish the CP dynamically, but it would NOT set the publish state. In other words: you could simply delete the component and orphan your DCPs in the broker. This was the case in 5.3, and probably 2009 as well. Not sure about 2011 though.

Comment: Ok - following the steps but everytime I drop the zip in I get "Phase: Deployer Prepare Phase failed, Unable to rename package to D:\tridion\incoming\Zip\tcm_0-11966-66560.Content.zip, Unable to rename package to D:\tridion\incoming\Zip\tcm_0-11966-66560.Content.zip"?

Comment: You probably need to rename the zip file, so it doesn't conflict with the one you started with. Change the second number in there (so 11966) in your case into something lower (since higher numbers will be generated later and might then lead to conflicts).

Comment: That could be a useful approach

Comment: Just to say that I tried Frank's suggestion but it didn't work. I always get the failed message :(

Comment: Given the error message, I suspect the problem remains the same: there is a conflicting file somewhere, causing the rename to fail. You'll have to figure out where the conflict comes from and work from there. Alternatively you can of course take Quirijn's suggestion and set up a new broker database.

Comment: Good news, I gave Franks' solution one more try - except this time after I'd copied the Zip  into the incoming folder, I ensured that the "Everyone" group had full control over the file and it worked! I've accepted Franks answer.

Comment: That's great news Neil. Although it's cumbersome, it typically beats having to create and populate a new broker DB.

Answer (score 4):

Compliments to Puf for creativity. I checked his approach with Tridion Customer Support and - although they say it is a grey area - they will allow this.

The only alternative is to create a new broker database and publish everything that was already published there. Then you can swap it with the live db.

Comment: Good that you confirmed Puf's approach with support. Otherwise - I'd have assumed that your approach was the only one with clear support.